# Maximum of quadratic function, given three obvious points

Tags: functions

> Given
>
> $$\begin{equation}f(x) = -2\times\frac{(x-102)(x-104)}{(100-102)(100-104)}+2\times\frac{(x-100)(x-104)}{(102-100)(102-104)}+2\times\frac{(x-100)(x-102)}{(104-100)(104-102)}\end{equation}$$
>
> Find the point $(x, f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is the maximum.

I've found some obvious points on the function
$$f(100)=-2\quad f(102)=f(104)=2$$

So there must be a solution between $x=100$ and $x=102$.

That's all I've found, how should I move further to find the maximum value?

Comment: The first and second term cancel each other.Also,it is a quadratic function not a cubic as mentioned in your title.(either of whose maximum value is not defined provided the domain is not restricted).

Comment: With that pointed out, I think it will be easy to find the function with three points known.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the problem properly? It seems quite pointless. As already pointed out, the first terms cancel and $f$ is unbounded. Furthermore, $f(102) = f(104) = 0$, not 2.

Comment: @JustANoob Fixed the typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: By the symmetry of quadratic function, the optimal point must be on the middle point of 102 and 104, which is 103. Hence the solution is $(103, f(103))$